# Python log rotation does not happen hourly

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, pyyaml, log-rotation

I have following yaml based logger configuration in my python application.

```
---
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
formatters:
  # formatters here

handlers:

  debug_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: formatter_json
    filename: debug.log
    when: h
    interval: 1
    backupCount: 180
    encoding: utf8

  info_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: formatter_json
    filename: info.log
    when: h
    interval: 1
    backupCount: 180
    encoding: utf8

  error_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    level: ERROR
    formatter: formatter_json
    filename: error.log
    when: h
    interval: 1
    backupCount: 180
    encoding: utf8

root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [debug_file_handler, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
```

My purpose is to rotate the log files hourly.

Now, in my application, I have a script that writes to log files every 5 minutes.But, I see all the logs getting written into the same file. Basically, it doesn't rotate the log files every hour.

Then I tried changing the config to below.

```
info_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: formatter_json
    filename: info.log
    when: m
    interval: 5
    backupCount: 180
    encoding: utf8
```

Now, as expected by that configuration, log files getting rotated every 5 minutes. By doing that, I just wanted to verify that the log rotation works.

I do not understand why it doesn't work for hourly rotation. (Actually, my end goal is to rotate files every 12 hours. Since it didn't work, I tried with one hour to test).

Can someone help me here understanding what's happening underneath and how to get it to work ?

Comment: Is this [tag:kivy]? Might be good to tag it so people with Kivy experience see it. edit: I didn't realise YAML could be used to configure logging in plain Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre], i.e. the minimal config plus some example program that just reads the config and logs? Which Python version are you using and did you try any others?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your posted configuration (with a formatter added) seems to rotate hourly just fine.

Comment: @PeterWood, MisterMiyagi, Vinay Thanks for your time. I did another sample project with same configuration and it works fine as mentioned also by Vinay. There has to be something wrong with my application. Ill check. Thanks again